# NewtonSoft incorrect deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

[This](https://api.frankerfacez.com/v1/room/leonardvdj) is what I'm trying to deserialize.

I let Visual Studio generate [these](https://hastebin.com/qoqupunibe.cpp) classes for deserialization.

But whenever I deserialize this data, I end up with the _56787 set being null. [Here's](https://hastebin.com/qikutatafu.json) the re-serialized data.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string temp = client.DownloadString($"https://api.frankerfacez.com/v1/room/leonardvdj");
    Rootobject FFZEmotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(temp);
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FFZEmotes));
}
```

This is the code I use to retrieve the JSON. I've checked "temp"s value, and it download's correctly.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Screenshots of code is not very helpful, please post a [mcve], along with test-data that is handled wrong.

Comment: Additionally, a key like that sounds awfully close to being the key of a dictionary, and not a property of an object, something which most such json-to-code generators doesn't seem to pick up on, so the class with that property might be better off replaced by a dictionary.

Comment: Be sure to include the value of `temp` in your [mcve].

Comment: JSON data stores in Name/Value pair; in your case json contains number as a name or key.This numbers is not parsing your data correctly. finally I would say your json is not in proper format

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen [Here's](http://leonardvdj.com/sharex/minimalcomplete.zip) a solution to recreate the issue.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen It works if I add [JsonProperty("56787")] above the "public _56787 _56878 { get; set; }" line, but this isn't a usable fix as it needs to match any number.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `sets` into a dictionary instead of a type and rename `_56787` to something more sensible:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Room room { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Set> sets { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public int _type { get; set; }
    public object css { get; set; }
    public object description { get; set; }
    public Emoticon[] emoticons { get; set; }
    public object icon { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```